# Creating mutually exclusive group using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff

When I create a group of raster layers in QGIS GUI I can toggle a checkbox to determine if this group will be mutually exclusive or not.

When I create the same group using the Python's API like:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsRaster, QgsRasterLayer, QgsProject

clu_group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().addGroup('MyGroup')
tifs = ['path/to/im1.tif', 'path/to/im2.tif', 'path/to/im3.tif']

for k_tif, tif in enumerate(tifs):
    raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(tif , f'l_{k_tif}')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(raster_layer, False)
    clu_group.addLayer(raster_layer)
```

the created group isn't mutually exclusive.

Is there any way to change it to be mutually exclusive?

Comment: https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeGroup.html#a985a1c8eba8456784d001fd94776c39b e.g. `clu_group.setIsMutuallyExclusive(True)`